# Is it possible to make http request to connect to any server from Looker?

Tags: looker

I need to connect to a server via a http request from Looker? Is it even possible? Unable to find any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can (kind of) do this:

1. You can use [Looker actions](https://docs.looker.com/reference/field-params/action) to make HTTP requests.
2. You could do something using the [extension framework](https://docs.looker.com/data-modeling/extension-framework/extension-framework-intro) and use javascript to make the http call